# Application closes in Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, debugging

My aplication runs on almost every Android device (on Galaxy Young, voice doesn't work),  but on Android 4.1.2, the application is closed after some time. Is this normal? How can I keep my application runnning? I start a service with a thread, where I put:

```
public class Servicechecker extends Service
{
    Thread th1;
    Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.d("DEBUG","Servicio Creado");
        g.setservicio(true);
        hilo();
    }
    public void hilo()
    {
        Log.d("DEBUG","en hilo");
        th1= new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100000000);
                        Log.d("Debug","Servicio");
                        /*if(g.getsms())
                        {
                            Intent intenttwo = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sms.class);
                            intenttwo.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            g.setnumero("2721700311");
                            g.setmensaje("Body");
                            startActivity(intenttwo);
                        }*/
                        System.gc();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.d("DEBUG","I1: " + e.toString());
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        th1.start();
    }
    protected void sendnotification (String title, String message) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        CharSequence tickerText = message;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = title;
        CharSequence contentText = message;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ProxSenET.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
        Log.d("DEBUG","Paso not");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        g.setservicio(false);
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

But it still closes.

Comment: post the stack trace.